# Can anyone help me with identify this Giant bike?

Tags: road-bike, frames, identify-this-bike, product-rec, giant

I need a name for this bike so I can look into it. It's going to be sold to me but I don’t want to get ripped off. Thanks!
[image]

Answer (score 7):

You should ask the seller for all the information you need about the bike, because a) they should know more than we do and b) if they can't give it to you readily then there is more risk that it is stolen. These things do happen!

Don't tell the seller this, but the name is usually written *on the frame*. If they can't manage that much then consider walking away.

Answer (score 5):

It looks like a 2017 Giant Contend SL2 Disc: https://www.giant-bicycles.com/gb/contend-sl-2-disc-2017.

The picture is quite grainy so it's hard to be 100% sure. Check if it has the Giant Conduct disc brake system to be sure.

Here's the image in the linked product page for the 2017 Giant Contend SL2 Disc:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to the site. Good shout on the 2017 GC SL2 D. Can you elaborate on the Giant Conduct brake system? Only because I don't see it on either the link or OP's photo so if anything it's simpler than that

Comment: I've edited in the image from the link you found. This will mean that if the link goes bad in future, the answer will remain strong. It also helps illustrate your answer in case users don't click the link

Comment: Thanks for editing in the photo.

The Conduct system combines a hydraulic fluid reservoir with the stem faceplate. This allows for a hybrid cable/hydraulic braking system, where standard brake cables run from the shifters to the reservoir, then hydraulic hoses from the reservoir to the calipers.

Here's Giant's page on the system: https://www.giant-bicycles.com/global/showcase/conduct

It was probably included on the bike in question as there was no Tiagra 4700-series hydraulic shifters in Shimano's range, so they couldn't have both completely hydraulic brakes and a Tiagra groupset.

Comment: Aha, confusion over; I didn't read the spec, only looked at the photo. The brakes in Giant's photo look to me like cable operated disc brakes, while the written spec says Conduct hydraulics. This [article](https://www.bikeradar.com/news/giants-new-entry-level-road-bike-the-contend/?image=4&type=gallery&gallery=1&embedded_slideshow=1) dated 2016 indicates cable only, while [this one](https://www.bikeradar.com/reviews/bikes/road-bikes/giant-contend-sl-2-disc-review/?image=2&type=gallery&gallery=1&embedded_slideshow=1) dated 2017 indicates the Conduct system on the same frame. Back to confused!

Comment: I agree that the photo looks like cable brakes - perhaps they decided to change the spec after all of the marketing material had already been produced. I know someone with this exact bike (hence why I recognised it), and their bike has the Conduct system.

Comment: indeed, it could be that the spec was changed quite late on. the one article looks like an early press launch with the whole range lined up, no Conduct. The second article looks hands on with a production model, perhaps this explains the differences. IF so, it could be that OP's bike is a bit of a rarity.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like a nice bike - not very old because disk brakes have only been on road bikes in the last ~5 years.

The top tube profile suggests an aluminium frame not carbon fibre, and the thickness of the fork tines/legs suggest they are carbon fibre.

Both tyres are a bit low on air so pump them up before you test-ride it.   And you should absolutely test ride it before buying.   As long as its comfortable for you, then its a good bike.

Do note that Giant's "lifetime frame warranty" only applies to the original purchaser.   Giant bikes aren't known for being counterfeited - the higher-end brands have much more of that.

When you test-ride, do a quick M check to make sure all the important parts are safe, not rattling or worn.  Look at the chain and drive train's state of wear, and look at rotors for wear.  You'll get an idea if its a low mileage garage queen or a worn-out commuter with tens of thousands of km on it.